# How do i update columns of two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I have the following structure for `Sales` and `Invoices` tables

**Sales**

```
  SaleNo int PK
  SaleDt Datetime PK
  Qnty
  UP
```

**Invoices**

```
InvoiceNo int  PK
InvoiceDT Datetime PK
SaleNo int   PK FK
SaleDT datetime PK FK
```

I want to update the SaleDT of the two table and I need to set it to value '2013-01-31 08:25:38.217'.
How do I do this?

Comment: Update PK I think is a bad idea

Comment: You can use ONUPDATE CASCADE...

Comment: Why is the timestamp part of the primary or foreign key? It seems like `SaleNo` (and `SaleNo`, `InvoiceNo` pairs on the child table) should be sufficient for unique identification, and that would eliminate the problem you're experiencing since you wouldn't need to duplicate it on the child table.

Comment: SaleNo can be duplicated in daily basis, so I need to make the PK not just SaleNo but also SaleDT

Answer (score 1):

try this..

-- First update value in one table, then in other

```
UPDATE        S
SET           S.SaleDT = 'your value'
FROM          SALE S
INNER JOIN    INVOICE I
ON            S.SaleNO = I.SaleNo


UPDATE      I
SET         I.SaleDT = 'your value'
FROM SALE   S
INNER JOIN  INVOICE I
ON          S.SaleNO = I.SaleNo
```

Comment: it does not work

Here is the error=**

    Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Invoices_Sales". The conflict occurred in database "POSSystemTest1", table "dbo.Invoices".
The statement has been terminated.**

So, one way to do is the break relationship between the tables and update separate then "Shahid Iqbal" answer would work : ) 

But in the real life one cannot break tables like that to make major updates??